# memory leak in simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-leaks, ios-simulator

Instruments show me a leak in simulator in the following code,

```
UIBarButtonItem *connectButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Connexion" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(pushViewController)];

    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:connectButton animated:animated];
    [connectButton release];
```

Do you see any leak ?? thanks

Comment: What kind of leaks does it report?

Comment: This code looks ok -- are you certain this is where the memory leak is being reported?

Comment: leaked Object : _NSCFType. Responsible Library : CoreGraphics. Responsible frame : CGTypeCreateInstanceWithAllocator

Comment: Leaks is showing you where the object was allocated, *not* where it was leaked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leaks is showing you *where the object was allocated*, not *where the object was leaked*.

While the two might be the same, it is often much more likely that the leak of an object is caused by an extra retain or missing release somewhere else.

Comment: Do you hava an idea why is a leak here : self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor]; ? i have tested this in device

Comment: I am sorry; i have not understand your answer

Comment: That line of code cannot possibly leak;  `clearColor` will return a singleton or autoreleased object.  You are immediately giving control to the navigation bar.  Unless you have created your own navigation bar class and are mismanaging the tintColo, that line of code cannot be the source of an allocation for a leak.

Comment: se my post please, what do you think ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004946/memory-leak-with-navbar

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any leaks in the code you posted.  That said, a couple questions:

1. How do you know that's where the leak is?
2. Any chance the getter for `navigationItem` is using `copy`?  If so, there could be a leak there.

Comment: In the stack trace in instruments. i haven't declared navigationItem using copy, i have just done self.navigationItem in my controller

Comment: and i have many leaks when i do this :self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];

Answer (score 0):

...and on device? You should check this on device. There are very, very few situations where you'd want to use the simulator for this kind of testing. It's not representative of how the device itself behaves. I'd recommend you test this on a device, and then if you're still seeing it come back here.

Comment: Do you hava an idea why is a leak here : self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor]; ? i have tested this in device.