# memory leak with navBar

Tags: iphone

Can you help me please to fix the memory leak ?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface NavBar : NSObject 
{
    NSString* nav;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* nav;

+ (NavBar *) sharedInstance;

@end


#import "NavBar.h"


@implementation NavBar

@synthesize nav;

-(void)dealloc
{
    [nav release];
}

+(NavBar *)sharedInstance 
{
    static NavBar *myInstance = nil;
    if (nil == myInstance) {
        myInstance  = [[[self class] alloc] init];
    }
    return myInstance;
}

@end
```

i have a leak here :

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    [NavBar sharedInstance].nav = @"navBar.png";
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:19/255.0 green:140/255.0 blue:130/255.0 alpha:1.0];

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

in the delegate of my app:

```
@interface UINavigationBar (CustomBackground)
- (void)drawRectCustomBackground:(CGRect)rect;
@end


@implementation UINavigationBar (CustomBackground)

- (void)drawRectCustomBackground:(CGRect)rect 
{

    if (self.barStyle == UIBarStyleDefault)
    {

            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NavBarStyles sharedInstance].navStyle];
            [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
            return;
    }

    [self drawRectCustomBackground:rect];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some point, you need to call

```
 [[NavBar sharedInstance] release];
```

or an equivalent.  Probably right before you exit.

Comment: Do so in the app delegate…in `applicationWillResignActive` (if you can recreate it in `applicationWillBecomeActive`) or `applicationWillTerminate`.

Comment: Don't bother;  if it is a singleton shared instance then, by definition, there should be only one and it should stick around for the lifetime of your app.  *There is no point in trying to release objects when your app is terminating.*

Comment: If you want clean "Build and Analyze" and Leak Instruments reports (which make it more likely that you'll use them and fix other problems), I would do the release.